# How can I extend a flow type for express$Request?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I am using `flow-typed`, so it has an `express` definition. In my code, I have:

```
isPayloadSignatureValid(req /*: express$Request */ ) {
  const rawBodyPayload = Buffer.from(req.rawBody).toString('utf8')
```

But flow complains, saying:

```
Cannot get req.rawBody because property rawBody is missing in express$Request [1].
```

In my `interfaces/express.js`, I have:

```
// @flow
/*::
type express$Request = exports.Request & {
  rawBody: string
}
export type { express$Request };
*/
```

And in my `.flowconfig`, I have:

```
[include]
./interfaces/.*
```

SO why isn't the extended `express$Request` having the `rawBody` property?

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to either export the `express$Request` type from `interfaces/express` or `declare` it in and add it as a library definition in order for Flow to pick it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not gonna get the type from `interfaces/express.js` when you actually use express. You'd need to import it and inject it yourself. Generally in this situation you'd want to just modify the express libdef from flow-typed directly. Also you should avoid using an intersection type here, you should spread the object types (`...`).